# object with latest date mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have 2 objects with `created_at` attribute.

I want to know the query with Which of these two objects is the most recent date

object 1:

```
#<User _id: 504726081d41c809e5000003, _type: "User", created_at: 2012-09-05 10:14:33 UTC >
```

object 2:

```
#<User _id: 503fb40f1d41c8255a000007, _type: "User", created_at: 2012-08-30 18:42:24 UTC >
```

### Edited

**This 2 object are inside array: something like:**

```
 [#<User _id: 504726081d41c809e5000003, _type: "User", created_at: 2012-09-05 10:14:33>, #<User _id: 503fb40f1d41c8255a000007, _type: "User", created_at: 2012-08-30 18:42:24>]
```

**I can not use `.last`. I need use lastest date.**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say:

```
User.order_by([:created_at, :desc]).limit(1).first #useful to include other ordering conditions
```

Or:

```
User.desc(:created_at).limit(1).first
```

---

Since your edit:

```
array.max_by{|u| u.created_at}
```

Comment: Thank you I have edited te question. The objects are inside array. Thank you

Comment: Thank you brother is correct both replies :D. Thank you very much!